# Button ActionListener runs both combo box choices at the same time why?

Tags: java, button, combobox, listener, actionlistener

Hello I have a problem with my comboBox. In app that im making my panel has a combo box with two choices and a button next to the combo box to proceed to the choice selected in the combo box but instead both if Statements run and no I have no idea why.

Combo box code is simple private JComboBox mainChoice = new JComboBox();

mainChoice.addItem("") etc...

```
class mainPanelGoButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        String choice = (String)mainChoice.getSelectedItem();

        System.out.printf(choice);

        if(choice == "View Passenger Details");
        {
            JTextField first = new JTextField();
            JTextField last = new JTextField();

            Object[] message = {  
                    "First Name:", first,  
                    "Last Name:", last
            };  

            int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Enter passenger name", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)  
            {  
                // Load passenger data
                p = dataHandler.getPassengerData(first.getText(), last.getText());
                if(p != null)
                {
                    updateTextfields( p);
                    // Display passenger data
                    getContentPane().removeAll();
                    getContentPane().add(passengerDetailsPanel);
                    setSize(400,340);
                    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                    printAll(getGraphics());
                }
            }
        }

        if(choice == "Add New Passenger")
        {
            if(displayPassengerInputForm());
            {
                // Display passenger data
                getContentPane().removeAll();
                getContentPane().add(passengerDetailsPanel);
                setSize(400,340);
                setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                validate();
                repaint();
                printAll(getGraphics());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

// EXAMPLE OF MY PROGRAM THAT RETURNS BOTH WINDOW A and WINDOW B

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame
{
private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
private JComboBox<String> mainChoice = new JComboBox<String>();
private JButton goButton = new JButton("GO");

public Frame()
{
    createMainPanel();
    this.add(mainPanel);
}


private void createMainPanel()
{
    // Fill choice box
    mainChoice.addItem("Find Passenger");
    mainChoice.addItem("Add New Passenger");

    // Set button

    goButton.addActionListener(new mainPanelGoButtonListener());
    goButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5,5));

    // Add to main panel
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,4,4));
    mainPanel.add(mainChoice);
    mainPanel.add(goButton);

}


class mainPanelGoButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {       
        if(mainChoice.getSelectedItem().equals("Find Passenger"));
        {
            // DISPLAYS WINDOW FOR INPUT
            System.out.printf(" WINDOW A ");

        }

        if(mainChoice.getSelectedItem().equals("Add New Passenger"));
        {
            // DISPLAYS WINDOW FOR INPUT
            System.out.printf(" WINDOW B ");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.setTitle("SSD Project");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(400,50);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Each time I press a button it prints out both Window A and Window B instead of one

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that you use `==` to compare Strings.

Don't use `==` to compare Strings as this compares if two String ***objects*** are the same, something that you are not interested in testing. Use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method which tests if two Strings contain the same characters, in the same order, with or without the same case respectively, and this is what you are really interested in.

- Next: be sure you use `if (something) { xxxx } else if (somethingElse) { xxxx }` to be sure that only one if block gets performed.
- Next: look up the CardLayout which will allow your GUI to change views much more cleanly.

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> do you mean: mainChoice.getSelectedItem().equals("Add New Passenger") ?? cause im still getting the same result ;

Yes, exactly. But on further reflection, your code above cannot be causing both if blocks to fire as the String == can't be true for both test Strings. Something else is causing your problem.

> could you give me some quick example?

Actually it would be better if you could create and post a [minimal runnable program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem for us.

Comment: do you mean: mainChoice.getSelectedItem().equals("Add New Passenger") ?? cause im still getting the same result ;/ could you give me some quick example?

Comment: I have found the mistake thanks for your time while writing the code i must have added ; at the end of if statment which caused the code in brackets to execute ^.^

Comment: @user3264021: indeed. Good pick-up. 1+